# JSON to CSV : Multiple Data Rows

Tags: java, json, database, csv, read-write

I have been trying to write to a CSV file from a JSON file using NorthConcepts datapipeline library in the following way, however I have problems. The data in the JSON file is either repeated or the fields are Seperated and written in different rows. For instance from the given code below I could have a combination of the following rows : Row 1 : CreatedAt, ID, Row 2 : CreatedAT, ID, IDString, Row 3 : CreatedAt, IDString likewise. I have about 30 fields and about 4 rows in the CSV file writing data for the same record but with split fields filled in. Would anyone know what the problem is? The JSON file I am reading from doesnt have repetitive data.

I read data the following way :

```
DataReader reader = new JsonReader(new File(FILE))
.addField("CreatedAt", "//array/object/created_at")
.addField("ID", "//array/object/id")
.addField("IDString", "//array/object/id_str")
.addField("Text", "//array/object/actualTweet")
```

Writing data the following way :

```
DataWriter writer = new  CSVWriter(new File("../Twix/files/x.csv" ));
JobTemplate.DEFAULT.transfer(reader, writer);
```

The library used : http://northconcepts.com/data-pipeline/
javadocs : http://northconcepts.com/data-pipeline/javadocs/

Example CSV :

```
  Name  ProfileImageURL Location    CreatedAt   FollowRequestSent   IsTranslator    DefaultProfile  FavouritesCount ContributorsEnabled
  The Guardian      London                      
  The Guardian      London                      
  The Guardian      London  Thu Nov 05 23:49:19 +0000 2009              130 
  The Guardian      London  Thu Nov 05 23:49:19 +0000 2009              130 
  The Guardian      London  Thu Nov 05 23:49:19 +0000 2009              130 
    http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2814613165/f3c9e3989acac29769ce01b920f526bb_normal.png          FALSE   FALSE   FALSE       FALSE
```

Here the URL given above is for the second column.

Comment: This doesn't really help, but I think I would convert the Json to a list of objects. One object representing a row of data from the ultimate csv file. Then have a CSV writer that adds the column headings and then writes each object as required. The blank object fields could become empty strings in the CSV file.

Comment: What are you passing into `JsonReader.addRecordBreak()`?

Comment: This is what i pass into addRecordBreak : //array/object. Although there are nested objects within this JSON i don't need them so not using them. Do you think this could be a problem?